# How to have unused apps not take up resources

Tags: storage, link2sd, auto-start

Is there a way I can have unused apps not take up resources?  Especially Internal memory and other resources not on Sd card.

I am already using Link2SD to move what I can to SD.

I know you can back them up and re install, I was hoping for something easier, like avoiding autostart.

Comment: Have you tried disabling an app? Also, give us more details... Which phone, which ROM, which Android version.

Comment: I can't see how I can disable an app - will check out

Comment: Samsung GT-S5660

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a third party app called [ES Task Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.taskmanager), which allows me to manually enable and disable autostarting for the most apps as I can see so far.
You didn't say if your Samsung is rooted or not so I need to mention that you need a rooted device to perform this via the Task Manager.

It might also be possible to transfer not only user installed apps but system apps as well with Link2SD while beeing on a rooted device. At least these system apps are shown by Link2SD, but I never really tried that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable these apps. This way the apps will not be running and won't be consuming any resources. You have not mentioned your Android version, so here's how you can disable an app in Jelly Bean, if you have another version of Android just look around the setting may be somewhere else.

```
Settings -> Apps -> All -> Select the app you want to disable -> Disable
```

You have also not mentioned what app you are talking about. Remember, this only works for system apps, and they will still take up space on internal memory. If you have a downloaded app, you may have to uninstall it.

Comment: I will check out, but its mostly for apps I don't use very often, like some apps for the train.  I am looking to the autostarts app and application backup.

Comment: I can't really check this.  Personally I thin Titanium Backup is the way to go.